# Cakephp unable to send email

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I want to use the cakePHP mailer system, but I am unable to send an email, I get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'CakeEmail' not found in D:... on line 100
```

I have the following defined in my controller:

```
 App::uses('AppController', 'Controller','CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

 // In the controller:
 public function search() {
      $email = new CakeEmail();
                    $email->from(array('noreply@assetchase.co.za' => 'Assetchase.co.za'));
                    $email->subject('result notification.');
                    foreach($emails as $value) {
                        $user = $this->User->find("first",array("fields" => array("username"),"conditions" => array("id" => $value)));
                        $email->to($user['User']['username']);
                        $email->send('A new notification, booyah!');
                        // Send an email with the username.
                    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have to modify **App::uses** because App::uses() only allows two arguments the class name and its location and you are passing 4 parameter instead

Try this

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

Here is the reference [uses](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/app#method-Appuses)

[Core Utility Library](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App%3a%3auses)

[Email Basic Usage](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html?highlight=cakeemail#CakeEmail)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common error that developers do at first, Change your `App::uses` and separate them:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

Because of the new way cake references the classes.